# MySQL Query Logging to Syslog-ng server

Tags: mysql, logging, syslog

Is it possible to log queries to a central syslog-ng server?  Need to have mysql query logs present in an existing centralized log server.

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration on a syslog-ng client :

```
source s_mysql_instance_1 {
        pipe("mysqld-1.error.log" log_prefix("mysqlsrv-instance_1"));
        unix-stream ("/dev/log");
        internal();
};

source s_mysql_instance_2 {
        pipe("mysqld-2.error.log" log_prefix("mysqlsrv-instance_2"));
        unix-stream ("/dev/log");
        internal();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer don't solved the problem. The log appear in syslog-ng server for few time and stops without show any error in cliente or server.

It can be a wrong timeout parameter in syslog-ng of client or server, but I could not find anything :(